# Valid SQL Server query returning empty in System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

Here is my query, it is on 2014 Adventure works.

```
DECLARE @l_RunSQL VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @l_RunSQL = COALESCE(@l_RunSQL + ' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM [', 'SELECT * FROM [') + TABLE_SCHEMA +'].['+ TABLE_NAME+']'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE [TABLE_TYPE] = 'BASE TABLE'
  AND [TABLE_NAME] LIKE 'Address';

EXEC (@l_RunSQL)
    WITH RESULT SETS
         (
             (
                 [AddressID] [INT],
                 [AddressLine1] [NVARCHAR](60),
                 [AddressLine2] [NVARCHAR](60),
                 [City] [NVARCHAR](30),
                 [StateProvinceID] [INT],
                 [PostalCode] [NVARCHAR](15),
                 [SpatialLocation] [GEOGRAPHY],
                 [rowguid] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER],
                 [ModifiedDate] [DATETIME]
             )
        );
```

I am able to run this in SSMS and I get the contents of the `Person.Address` table as desired.

In C#, I create a connection node and then a command node and try and execute query like so:

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly))
{
     schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
}
```

And the reader results come back empty. Why is this command valid in SSMS but not using C# ?

The connection is of type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` and the command is of type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are executing with `CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly`,
which returns column information only, without data, see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.commandbehavior?view=netframework-4.7.2).

> The query returns column information only. When using SchemaOnly, the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server precedes the statement being executed with SET FMTONLY ON.

To access the returned data from the query, just execute as below.

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // Access your data here
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0])); // Column AddressID
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: But shouldn't I at least be seeing my schema info, like what is in the result set?

Comment: Might have to do with the `WITH RESULT SETS` feature; with this in the query `GetSchemaTable` returns `null`. For a 'regular' query (eg. `select * from sometable`) `CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly` is OK to return the schematable. At least, without `CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly` you can access the schematable.